# Looking for the name of a theorem relating Shannon entropy to largest probability

Tags: information-theory

Based on the definition of the Shannon entropy, 
$$
H = \sum_x p(x) \log \frac{1}{p(x)}
$$
for a probability distribution $p$ defined on a discrete set of outcomes $x$, one can bound the probability of any event
$$
\forall x, p(x) \le e^{-H},
$$

using the fact that $\log \frac{1}{p(x)} \ge \log \frac{1}{\max_x' p(x')}$ for any $x$.
Is there a name for this inequality?

Comment: It is just combination of log being monotonic function, p being non negative and between 0,1 and 1/x flips size. Why do you need a name for it?

Comment: @mathreadler thanks for the reply! I don't *need* one, I was just wondering if a well known name exists that I could use to reference it.

Comment: I believe the inequality is not true. For example, consider the case of two outcomes: $p(1) = 0.9$ and $p(2) = 0.1$. Then $H = 0.32$ (in nats) and $e^{-H} = 0.72$. It is not true that $p(1) = 0.9 \le 0.72$.

Comment: @Artemy thanks! - no wonder I couldn't find the name:)

Answer (score 0):

The theorem is false. What we have, calling $p_M$ the maximum over $p_x$, and using nats, is

$$ H = \sum_x p_x \log (1/p_x) \ge \sum_x p_x \log (1/p_M) = \log(1/p_M) $$

Hence $-H \le \log p_M$ and $p_M \ge e^{-H} $. So, you got the inequality backwards - and it doesn't let you conclude anything about the other $p_x$ values.

Comment: Ah good point, thanks!